# Converting .bat script into MS PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm brand new to coding and in the process of converting this script to Powershell. I'm confused on first for loop. What is "skip=2" doing, what is %%A and what's the point of running a systeminfo?

```
@echo off

SET file=f:\srvapps\webdata\wwwroot\VMuptime\HMIlist.txt
SET OUpath="OU=Packaging,OU=Process Control,OU=XP Workstations Remediated,DC=fcb,DC=corp,DC=anheuser-busch,DC=com"
SET output=f:\srvapps\webdata\wwwroot\VMuptime\uptimes.txt
SET modified=f:\srvapps\webdata\wwwroot\VMuptime\modifiedUptimes.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion1

If exist %output% del /F %output% 
If exist %modified% del /F %modified%
rem pause 
date /T >>%output%
for /F "skip=2"  %%A in (%hmi%) do (
    systeminfo /s %%A | findstr /c:"System Up Time" /c:"Host Name">>%output%
)
rem pause

date /T >>%modified%
for /F "tokens=1-10" %%G in (%output%) do (
    if "%%G"=="Host" (
    set line1=%%I 
    )  else echo !line1!, %%J %%K %%L %%M %%N %%O>>%modified%   
)
```

Comment: [Powershell learning resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/more-powershell-learning?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: This script is taking a list of computers and running `systeminfo` on each to get the system boot time and then logging it to a file. That tells you what you need to learn in PowerShell and you can forget the rest of this batch file.                Step 1. Read a list of computers       2. For Each, retrieve the computer name and boot time, 3. Add it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a .bat file question. %hmi% is a variable not shown here that is set to a filename. Then skip=2 skips 2 lines in the file, and %%A gets set to each hostname in the file after that. systeminfo is run on each hostname and the output is searched for the uptime.

That part in powershell would be:

```
$hmi = 'file'
foreach ($a in get-content $hmi | select-object -skip 2) {
  systeminfo /s $a | select-string 'system up time','host name' 
}
```

I don't get an up time when I try it.